# WCF Service method that uses byte[]

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, memory-management

I have a WCF service written in C# and is hosted as a windows service.
The key and widely used method by most of the client is as shown in the method signature.

public string storeDocument(byte[] document)

The byte[] is passed to few shared methods before it gets stored in the database.

How do I cleanup the memory?

As this method is called by many clients and is widely used, and we recently noticed that the memory usage by this service on the server is 60 to 100 MB and CPU usage sometimes go up to 80%.

I would like to know is there any way I can make sure that it doesn't use that much memory.

Please help.

Comment: Have you run a profiler on the service? [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or suchlike? It may be that the lifetime of the `byte[]` is not actually the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF also supports streaming. If you use large chunks of data, maybe that is a better solution. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx